# RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (64x4 and 8x50)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pytorch, neural-network

Code in PyTorch that tries to predict the next 6 numbers of the megasena based on data from previous contests using a csv file.

The error seems to be related to the architecture of the neural network.

```
# define the neural network architecture
class LotteryNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LotteryNet, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(8, 50)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(50, 20)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(20, 6)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
```

The error happens in neural network training.

```
# prepare the training data
train_data = torch.tensor(data[["Dia", "Mes", "Ano", "Concurso", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]].values, dtype=torch.float32)

# train the neural network
for i in range(10000):
    # shuffle the data
    idx = torch.randperm(train_data.shape[0])
    shuffled_data = train_data[idx]

    # split the data into batches
    batch_size = 64
    num_batches = int(np.ceil(shuffled_data.shape[0] / batch_size))
    for j in range(num_batches):
        start_idx = j * batch_size
        end_idx = min((j + 1) * batch_size, shuffled_data.shape[0])
        batch_data = shuffled_data[start_idx:end_idx]

        # prepare the input and output tensors
        x = batch_data[:, :-6]
        y = batch_data[:, -6:]

        # zero the parameter gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # forward + backward + optimize
        outputs = net(x)
        loss = criterion(outputs, y)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

Error.

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[48], line 23
     20 optimizer.zero_grad()
     22 # forward + backward + optimize
---> 23 outputs = net(x)
     24 loss = criterion(outputs, y)
     25 loss.backward()
```

RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (64x4 and 8x50).

Comment: `self.fc1 = nn.Linear(8, 50)` The number of input features to the first layer must match the number of features input to the neural network. You only have 4 input features, but the layer expects 8.